# Why is the use of std::min in these fold expressions undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Thanks to [Can I implement max(A, max(B, max(C, D))) using fold expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404503/can-i-implement-maxa-maxb-maxc-d-using-fold-expressions) I'm aware of one working approach to use std::min in a fold expression(`min2` below). However, I'm curious why the below approaches `min1` and `min3` are considered undefined behavior(seemingly given the warning)?

Per my understanding the expression should evaluate in both cases from left to right, constantly updating `myMin` and assign the last value back to `myMin`. Additionally, the final answer is also always correct on both gcc and clang.

```
template <typename... Args>
auto min1(const Args&... anArgs) {
    constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(anArgs);
    auto myMin = std::get<0>(std::tuple(anArgs...));
    myMin = std::get<N-1>(std::tuple((myMin = std::min(myMin, anArgs))...));
    return myMin;
}

template <typename... Args>
auto min2(const Args&... anArgs) {
    return std::min({anArgs...});
}

template <typename... Args>
auto min3(const Args&... anArgs) {
    auto myMin = (anArgs, ...);
    myMin = ((myMin = std::min(myMin, anArgs)), ...);
    return myMin;
}
```

The warnings are:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto min1(const Args& ...) [with Args = {int, int, int}]':
main.cpp:26:30:   required from here
main.cpp:8:45: warning: operation on 'myMin' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
    8 |     myMin = std::get<N-1>(std::tuple((myMin = std::min(myMin, anArgs))...));
      |                                      ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:45: warning: operation on 'myMin' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto min3(const Args& ...) [with Args = {int, int, int}]':
main.cpp:29:30:   required from here
main.cpp:20:10: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   20 |     auto myMin = (anArgs, ...);
      |          ^~~~~
main.cpp:20:10: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
main.cpp:21:11: warning: operation on 'myMin' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
   21 |     myMin = ((myMin = std::min(myMin, anArgs)), ...);
```

[Coliru Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de4fae01909e301c)

Finally, the reason I'm looking into alternate approaches(specifically min1) is because I'm trying to use a 3rd party library for which the comma operator is deprecated and I was wondering if this can still be solved using fold expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have any undefined behavior. Note that the warnings say:

> warning: operation on 'myMin' **may be** undefined [-Wsequence-point]

(my emphasis)

This warning, in both `min1` and `min3`, comes from the expression

```
((myMin = std::min(myMin, anArgs))...)
```

If the parameter pack has 3 elements as it does in your case, this expression will get instantiated as:

```
((myMin = std::min(myMin, __anArgs0)) , 
 ((myMin = std::min(myMin, __anArgs1)) , 
  (myMin = std::min(myMin, __anArgs2))))
```

where `__anArgs0` etc are just identifiers generated by the implementation. You can see this on [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/c045b778).

There's no unsequenced operations in this expression that I can see. I'm not really sure why these warnings are being generated, though I'm fairly sure they're false positives.

<s>The expressions between the `,` are unsequenced, that is true, and hence you get the warning that the entire expression may be undefined. However, since it doesn't matter in which order you compute the 3 different `std::min` calls, you don't have undefined behavior, and you are always going to get the same result.</s>

The compiler doesn't know this information though, and so it gives you the warning.

You don't get a warning with `min2` because the arguments are within a initalizer list, where the order of evaluation of the arguments is well defined.

Comment: "The expressions between the , are unsequenced" -- not quite: [Rule 9](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) starting with C++11 guarantees the evaluation order of the comma operator. The most important guarantee is that all side effects of the left hand side expression is sequence before the value computation of the right hand side operator, so you can't evaluate `myMin` in the two or all three calls to `std::min` before applying the side effect of the assignment operator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hmm, that does seem to be the case. Where is the warning coming from I wonder? Clang shows the same warnings as well.

Comment: Beats me. I do not see any undefined behavior, based on my read. I think it's a false alarm.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I can't see any UB either. The fact that both Clang and GCC produce the same warning makes me think there's something deeper going on though, even if it's a false alarm. I should have given it more careful thought before writing up the answer. Oh well, I'll leave it up while I think about it anyway.

Comment: Well, I could see an argument for the warning in the first parameter pack expansion, as an old warning that does not apply. The first parameter pack expansion is not a folded comma expression, it provides parameters to `std::tuple`'s constructor, and when this is interpreted as a function call pre-C++11 the function call's parameters' side effects are not sequences with each other. Except that std::tuples and parameter packs did not exist until C++11.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would understand a pre-c++11 warning carrying over, but that happening in 2 different compilers seems a lot less likely. Possible, of course.

Comment: I think it's the extra assignment outside the fold. `x = x = 1;` was undefined before 11.

Comment: @T.C. Oh, I didn't know that about pre-11, thanks. Strangely, gcc still [warns](https://godbolt.org/z/d4PfW3) about that. But if that's the explanation, then like the `x=x=1;` case, the warning should point to the assignment outside the fold, right? In this case it points to the inner one.